# Science-fi style sound themes

Tags: windows, audio, themes

Where can I get those Science-fi movie style sound themes for my Windows xp
Teet-teet-teet-.tit…tit

Like that…

Comment: I have to hand it to you. The teet-teet-teet-tit made my day :))

Comment: Are you looking for any particular film, or just sci-fi sounds in general? And have you searched using Google already?

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the Star Trek (LCARS) sounds at http://www.lcarscom.net/sounds.htm. Look for the sounds under the heading "Computer Effects".

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You'll find several sci-fi related sounds on [this website](http://www.desktopstarships.com/sounds.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to start goolging. One site is [www.themeworld.com](http://www.themeworld.com), and one of today's highlighted themes is [Star Trek - Borg - Resitance is futile](http://www.themeworld.com/cgi-bin/preview.pl/themes/borg2.zip). The ultimate solution is find exactly the images and sounds you want and custom build your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

For the (often involuntarily) funny 70s sci-fi series [UFO](http://us.imdb.com/title/tt0063962/):

http://ufoseries.com/soundEffects/index.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.activewin.com/themes/scifi/scifi_s_s.shtml